# DAO persistence: only one method to store a complex data object?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Here we have:

```
public final class Product {

 Integer productId;
 String description;
 ...

 public Product(final Integer productId, final String descripcion, ...) {
    this.product_id = productId;
    this.description = description;
    ...
 }

 public Integer getProductId() { ... }
 public String getDescription() {...}

 ...

}
```

An then:

```
public final ProductDetails {

 Integer productId;
 String serialNumber;
 ...
 public ProductDatails(final Integer productId, final serialNumber, ...){ ... }
 public Intger getProductId() { ... }
 public String getSerialNumber { ... }
 ...

}
```

So, in order to build a DAO which persists the data the two classes contain, the question is that if it is a good practice to do as follows:

```
    public Interface IProductDAO {

      public void saveProduct(final Product product);
      public void saveProductDetails(final ProductDetails productDetails);

    }
```

or:

```
public Interface IProductDAO {
 public void saveProduct(final Product product, final ProductDetails productDetails);
```

I have been taking in consideration to refactor the two classes into one as follows:

```
public final class Product {

 Integer productId;
 String description;
 ProductDetails productDetails;
 ...

 public Product(final productId productId, final String description, final ProductDetails productDetails,...) {

   if(productId!=productDetails.getProductId())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("ProductID is not the same");

   ...

 }
```

}

So:

```
 public Interface IProductDAO {            
      public void saveProduct(final Product product);                               
 }
```

I would like to know which one is the most 'natural' approach according best software development practices. If there are other approaches, they will be welcomed as well.

Comment: I like your last one.  It seems logical that ProductDetails be part of a Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `Bertrand Meyer - Object Oriented Software Construction (2Ed)`, the class Product should contains a reference to ProductDetails because exists a strong relationship between these classes.

On the other hand, it is a good practice extending from the Product class to produce a new one ProductDetails class. In both cases, a DAO should be as follows:

```
public void saveProduct(final Product product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Approach is that you have two java classes. One is the product and the second is the  ProductDetails in which you have more details of the product. When the user clicks on the product, then you can fetch this class  to show more details for this particular item.

So the most basic details which are required to be shown in teh search page can come in the product class.

```
class Product {

 Integer productId;
 String description;
 @OneToOne
 @Basic(Fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 ProductDetails details;

 public Product(final Integer productId, final String descripcion, ...) {
    this.product_id = productId;
    this.description = description;
    ...
 }


 public Integer getProductId() { ... }
 public String getDescription() {...}

 ...

}
class ProductDetails{
 Integer productId;//any Id
String description;
//Storing a HD picture and other getters and setters
}
//details of the class
}
```

Comment: I don't consider using hibernate or another ORM. In fact, the point is how to implement this situation with a oop strategy or a design pattern.